# QGIS Profile Tool plugin with wrong units

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, profile

I am using QGIS 2.18. I installed the plugin Profile Tool and I am trying to do a terrain profile from a DEM. I am working in projection WGS 84.

The profile I made with that plugin doesn't have the proper length units. The vertical scale is right, in meters, but the horizontal one is wrong. Instead of the numbers of meters, it appears: 0,01...0,02...

Does anyone know how to fix this? When I use the QGIS scale the units are okay. Only the Profile Tool is wrong.

Comment: Does it have to be WGS84? Reprojecting it to a coordinate system in meters would fix the problem.

Comment: Hi Lennert, thanks for your help. I am not a surveyor. I don´t know much of this subjects. Can you tell me which is the best coordinate system to work in meters in Angola (Africa)?

Comment: Hi,
I am checking around on https://epsg.io/?q=Angola%20kind%3APROJCRS . There might be a few, depending on your specific area. Or you might be able to use EPSG:3857 . Not sure.